# How to create Custom Data Annotation Validators

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

Wanting to create custom data annotation validation. Are there any useful guides / samples on how to create them?

Firstly:
StringLength with minimum and maximum length. I'm aware .NET 4 can do this, but want to do the same in .NET 3.5, if possible being able to define minimum length only (at least x chars), maximum length only (up to x chars), or both (between x and y chars).

Secondly:
Validation using modulus arithmetic - if the number is a valid length, I wish to validate using the Modulus 11 algorithm (I have already implemented it in JavaScript, so I guess it would just be a simple porting?)

**Update:**
Solved second problem, was just a case of copying over the JavaScript implementation and making a few tweaks, so don't need a solution for that.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

To create a custom data annotation validator follow these gudelines:

1. Your class has to inherit from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` class.
2. Override `bool IsValid(object value)` method and implement validation logic inside it.

That's it.

### IMPORTANT Caution

Sometimes developers check that value is not null/empty and return false. This is *usually* incorrect behaviour, because that's on `Required` validator to check which means that your custom validators should only validate non-null data but return `true` otherwise (see example). This will make them usable on mandatory (required) and non-mandatory fields.

### Example

```
public class StringLengthRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int Minimum { get; set; }
    public int Maximum { get; set; }

    public StringLengthRangeAttribute()
    {
        this.Minimum = 0;
        this.Maximum = int.MaxValue;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
        {
            int len = strValue.Length;
            return len >= this.Minimum && len <= this.Maximum;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

All properties can be set in attribute as you wish to set them.
Some examples:

```
[Required]
[StringLengthRange(Minimum = 10, ErrorMessage = "Must be >10 characters.")]

[StringLengthRange(Maximum = 20)]

[Required]
[StringLengthRange(Minimum = 10, Maximum = 20)]
```

When a particular property isn't set, its value is set in the constructor, so it always has a value. In above usage examples I deliberately added the `Required` validator as well, so it's in sync with the above **caution** I've written.

### Important

So this validator will still work on your model value that's not required, but when it's present it validates (think of a text field in a web form, that's not required, but if a user enters a value in, it has to be valid).

Comment: so, in case of null value should isValid return true?

Comment: So how do you add extra options, e.g. `[MyValidator(Min=1, Max=20)]`, Where both Min/Max (or just one) are optional?

Comment: @onof: Yes. In that case it should return `true`.

Comment: @Sam: I edited my answer and included an example of exactly what you're trying to do in the first scenario.

Comment: @Rap it works for me in MVC 5. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679289(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: modelstate is always valid

  [Required]
        [StringLengthRange(Minimum = 3, ErrorMessage = "Must be >3 characters.")]
        public string BookName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

Comment: How can  i register this ValidationAttribute in global.aspx?
Im trying to use this code: `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(NumericAttribute), typeof(???));`

Answer (score 14):

Use the [`CustomValidationAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) together with a validate function with signature

```
public static ValidationResult Validate(MyType x, ValidationContext context)
```

**Example (for a string property)**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MyClass
{
    [CustomValidation(typeof(MyClass), "Validate")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public static ValidationResult Validate(string x, ValidationContext context)
    {
        return (x == "valid")
            ? new ValidationResult(null)
            : ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the ValidationContext context argument used for?

Comment: @petryuno1 You could use it to get the model if you happen to need to look at other properties in your vlaidation. e.g., var model = (MyClass)context.ObjectInstance;

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old topic but I had trouble finding the answer I actually wanted until I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58705290/11656446).

To summarise it, you need to configure the service on startup, creating appropriate objects that handle the error you want to return:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = (context) =>
            {
                var errors = context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors.Select(p => new ErrorModel()
               {
                   ErrorCode = ((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                    ErrorMessage = p.ErrorMessage,
                    ServerErrorMessage = string.Empty
                })).ToList();
                var result = new BaseResponse
                {
                    Error = errors,
                    ResponseCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    ResponseMessage = ResponseMessageConstants.VALIDATIONFAIL,

                };
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(result);
            };
       });
```