# MVC4 validate Date to be today or after?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, date, razor

I have a playlist Model class in MVC4 that has a Date property, and when a user creates it, I want them not to be able to specify a date before today (so today or after).

Here's part of my Playlist class:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Incorrect date format.")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

How do I add validation for this "range"? Right now it's only validating to see if it's a valid date, but 11/30/2012 is valid and won't throw up any errors even though it was yesterday.

I'm using Razor for my Views. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733068/mvc-model-range-validator may help

Answer (score 1):

You can't validate against dynamic values using the Range attribute. You can create your own validator based on ValidationAttribute that validates the date against the current or a calculated date. Or you can use the IValidatableObject interface in your model class (buddy class to stop it getting overwritten by EF), and validate the properties you want there.