# Model date Range Validator in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rangevalidator

I use the below url code for date validation in mvc, but it is not showing the error.

"[MVC Model Range Validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733068/mvc-model-range-validator/)"

any help?

Comment: Where it is not showing error? `Client Side or Server Side`? the example link not implemented client side validation adaptor method

Comment: I am new to mvc, so i need to validate at the server side?

Comment: [Check this out](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+mvc3+jquery+validation)

Comment: so In controler, I need to use modelstate.isvalid to validate? am i right? any other way to display the error in page it self as showing the error when using [Required]?

Comment: Yes for Server side and implement client side also for double check

Comment: thank you for answering, so [required] is sever side or client side?   is there any way to display in page?

Answer (score 0):

Your comment in that question says (ErrorMessage="") which will give a blank error message and ergo you will not see a message. delete this statement to use the default or write your own.

Comment: sorry it is my mistake, i use the error message , but it is not showing.

Comment: could you post the actual code you are using, I know you say you are using the same code but you may have made an error whilst altering it for your needs. without this I cant really say whats wrong.

Comment: In model i use below code

[Required(ErrorMessage="Date field is requireddd")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DateRange(ErrorMessage = "Must be between 18 and 65 years ago")]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

Comment: if this is a custom attribute, did you remember to set the error message in the constructor of the custom attribute? it may be recieving the error message but not setting the error message property in the base class