# RequiredAttribute for DateTime if field empty or wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

The `RequiredAttribute` works for `string` but not `DateTime`. For example:

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
```

If `Name` is empty the Validation shows error, but if `Birthdate` is empty then nothing happens. I looked at:

[ASP MVC 5 Client Validation for Range of Datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182606/asp-mvc-5-client-validation-for-range-of-datetimes)

and

[MVC Model Range Validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733068/mvc-model-range-validator)

but still doesn't work for the `DateTime`

Comment: The `[Required]` attribute does work for `DateTime` and if you clear the value in the textbox, then a validation message will be shown assuming your view is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DateTime` is a struct, structs are "value type", not "reference type", so their default value are not `null`, for `DateTime` it is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`, `int` has its default value as `0`.

`string` type is a "reference type", all reference type have their default value as `null`.

So if you want to check if a value type is `null` you should create it as `Nullable`.

Like this:

```
public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
```

Or

```
public Nullable<DateTime> Birthdate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 5):

i think DateTime has a standard value so instead of required you should add a range attribute

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "01/01/1900", "01/01/2100", ErrorMessage="Date is out of Range")]
```

somthing like this should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to make `DateTime` nullable, yet still interpret the default value of 0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM (`DateTime.MinValue`) as "missing", simply create your own validator:

```
public class RequiredDateTimeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public RequiredDateTimeAttribute()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is DateTime))
            throw new ArgumentException("value must be a DateTime object");

        if ((DateTime)value == DateTime.MinValue)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: @NET7 contributor

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `Birthdate` property is not nullable, so it always will have a value, if changed to:

```
public Nullable<DateTime> Birthdate { get; set; }
```

then the required attribute will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Axel Bouttelgier's answer, the code would look like this:

Server side code

```
[Display(Name = "Disconnect Service")]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "01/01/1900", "01/01/2100" )]
public DateTime Disconnect Service { get; set; }
```

View code

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

The validation would look like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use kendo ui component in EditorTemplates and in Date.cshtml then when default date is DateTime.Now

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model DateTime?
    @if (Model.ToString() == "0001-01-01T00:00:00")
    {
        @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m).Format("yyyy/MM/dd").HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width: 20em", type = "text" }).Value(DateTime.Now).Footer("Today -  #=kendo.toString(data, 'dddd  yyyy/MM/dd') #")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m).Format("yyyy/MM/dd").HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width: 20em", type = "text"}).Value(Model).Footer("Today-  #=kendo.toString(data, 'dddd  yyyy/MM/dd') #")
    }
```

and in viewmodel class use

```
[UIHint("Date")]
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
```