# StackOverflow with TryValidateObject if the object is valid

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I am using `Validator.TryValidateObject()` to validate an object that uses data annotations. When the object is invalid, the code executes fine. However, if it is valid, a stackoverflow error is produced.

Here is my method:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext vc)
{
    vc = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);
    List<ValidationResult> a = new List<ValidationResult>();

    Validator.TryValidateObject(this, vc, a,true);

    foreach (var item in a)
        yield return item;

    if (Name == "Arbitary")
        yield return new ValidationResult("Bad Name.", new[] { "Name" });

}
```

It seems that `TryValidateObject` is internally calling my method `Validate` also.

My goal with this method is to validate all the DataAnnotations for my object, and then add on some complex validation logic afterwards - so I assumed that `TryValidateObject` would check data annotations, then afterwards I could place my own validation logic.

As it stands, my method works if the data is invalid - it will report the ValidationResults produced from the DataAnnotations, and also add a ValidationResult if the name is "Arbitary", but I get this stackoverflow if the data is valid.

Any ideas? How can I validate the data annotations of my object in a way that doesn't result in my own `Validate` method being called? Alternatively, How do I resolve this stack overflow?

Note that my class implements the `IValidatableObject` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than inheriting from Validate could you implement your own data annotation attribute to perform custom validation, as per this SO question?

[How to create Custom Data Annotation Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators)

Comment: Thanks, I may do this, but I want to be able to work out whether my object will be accepted into the database before trying to save it: something like `if (Model.Validate().Count() == 0) {Database.Save(Model);}`. At the moment I have to `catch` an exception where trying to `Save()` to the database, which is horribly inefficient.

Comment: If you adopt this approach you can still call Validator.TryValidateObject manually to check before submitting.