# read Attributes parameter values from config file

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Is it possible to load attributes values from config file? For example I have attribute below which cache property return value. This attribute used more than 10 times in application and I would like to load second attribute parameter(1800 seconds) from config file.

```
[Cache(CacheType.Absolute, 1800, CacheLocation.Memory)]
```

Comment: The attributes are  evaluated at compile time, so not sure if it could be configurable... will keep an eye for the answers

Comment: MVC has such attributes, I just can't find implementation for my own custom attributes.

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

I thinks You can do this by writing your `Attributes` like this:

[How to create Custom Data Annotation Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators)