# How do I make custom Validators in C# Code-First in EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have tried this:
[How to create Custom Data Annotation Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators)
But Visual Studio says that the namespace:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute;
doesnt exist.
I use EF 5.....
What shall I do?

Comment: Add the namespace to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to the System.Componentmodel.DataAnnotations namespace.

Comment: right-click references-folder in your project and click add reference. Then select Framework and check the box left to the namespace to add the namespace to your project.