# Is it possible to use the Required ValidationAttribute with value types?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I've decorated a class with:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required.")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

But when validating it with code:

```
   for each (PropertyInfo prop in Me.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
        if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Length = 0)
        {
            for each (ValidationAttribute validatt in prop.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(ValidationAttribute), True))
            {
                if (!validatt.IsValid(prop.GetValue(Me, Nothing))
                {
                    retval.Add(New PropertyValidationError(prop.Name, string.Format("There is a problem with the {0} property. It is flagged with the {1}", prop.Name, validatt.GetType.Name), validatt.ErrorMessage));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm finding that a value of `0` is being treated as fulfilling the "requiredness", which is not what I intended (in fact, I wanted to allow any value *other than* zero) - is it my validation code doing the wrong thing, or is there a way to use decorate with a `ValidationAttribute` that will fail for default values for value types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using a value type, such as `decimal`, it's *impossible to not have a value*.  As such, that attribute is effectively meaningless.

It would be a better idea to use [`[Range]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx), as this allows you to specify meaningful values.  However, this will not allow you to handle "any non-zero value" (though you could easily handle any positive non-zero value).

Your criteria, as stated, would require creating a [custom validation attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413875/65358) to validate, as "any value other than default(T)" is not a built-in validation.

Comment: Given I want to have *any value other than zero*; Looks like I mioght have to create a custom attribute?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yeah - If you want "any positive value" you could use `[Range]`, but for any value, you'd need a custom validation attribute.

Answer (score 2):

What about make you value type variable nullable?

```
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: I still wanted 0 to be considered invalid, which this solution wouldn't do

Answer (score 1):

Use the range validation attribute.

```
[Range(min, max, ErrorMessage )]
```

Comment: That doesn't work for allowing any negative or any positive value