# How to change the default error message of built-in ValidationAttributes?

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I would like to replace the default error message for for example `RequiredAttribute` or `RegularExpressionAttribute` with my own messages, so that I wouldn't need to specify the explicit `ErrorMessage` at attribute usage.

EDIT: Last part of the sentence means that I'm aware of the ability to specify my own `ErrorMessage` at attribute usage, and I would like to avoid it for keeping the project DRY.

Is it possible somehow? I haven't found any related property in the .NET library, and I currently have no idea how I could replace the .NET resources where the default messages are stored.

Comment: Why exactly do you need another way when you can pass your **own** error message with RequiredAttribute?

Comment: Because I would like a common message which I'm using in most cases. Now I need to repeat it at every usage of the attribute.

Comment: Cool, better you create a custom attribute! See Richard's answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your own version of the `[Required]` attribute that has a default message that you want. If you only want to use a custom error message have it inherit from `RequiredAttribute` so you can take advantage of the same `IsValid` logic

```
public class MyRequired : RequiredAttribute
{
    public MyRequired()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "Custom Validation Error Message.";
    }
}
```

If you need even finer control over other validation behaviors, you can [create your own DataAnnotation Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators/3413875#3413875).

```
public class MyRequired : ValidationAttribute
{
    public MyRequired() : base("My Custom Message")
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //Your custom validation logic
        return (value != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this way but I hoped for a nicer one. Anyway why not just not override the IsValid function?

Comment: ?  `IsValid` is being overridden.  I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: It's easier to override the relevant attribute (e.g. RequiredAttribute) rather than ValidationAttribute where you also need to implement `IsValid` again.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that you've inherited from ValidationAttribute, I thought you've inherited from RequiredAttribute and that's why I questioned why you've overridden the IsValid method. Sorry for the not too correct english sentence too :)

Comment: Ok yes I see what you mean, give me a few minutes to update.  This will currently work, but your suggestions are another improvement.

Comment: @Richard thanks for the extra advice.  Updated answer.