# Custom Validation attribute does not immediately clear error when value is fixed C# .net6 Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I have a custom validation attached to a property. The validation works as expected except that when it shows that the field needs to be fixed, the error does not immediately clear when the issue is fixed like what the build in validations does. The error does not stop me from submitting my form but it seems when the error is displayed it then revalidates on the button submit click. How can I make it behave like what the default validations do i.e. when the field is incorrect it shows the error and when the field is corrected the error immediately goes away?

below is the implementation of the validation

```
public class RequireGreaterThanZeroAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var objectValue = value.GetType().ToString().ToUpper() == "SYSTEM.DECIMAL" ? Convert.ToDecimal(value) : (int)value;
            if (objectValue > 0)
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            else
                return new ValidationResult($"{validationContext.DisplayName} must be greater than zero.");
        }
        catch
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"{validationContext.DisplayName} must be greater than zero.");
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the markup where the property is being used

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Amount</label>
       <InputNumber @bind-Value="@Transaction.Amount"  type="text" class="form-control required"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the Model property is defined as

```
[RequireGreaterThanZero]
public decimal Amount { get; set; } = 0.00M;
```

The Submit button is like below

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" style="width:100%" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary @BuyClass @SellClass @UpdateClass @ReverseClass" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> @ButtonText</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

While testing the solution provided by @MrCakaShaunCurtis, what i have noted is that this issue has something to do with the DataAnnotationsValidator when you use

```
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
```

instead of

```
<ValidationMessage For="() => Transaction.Amount" />
```

This is when the message doesnt go away. With

```
<ValidationMessage For="() => Transaction.Amount" />
```

the message behaves correctly.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis , can you try using the

```
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
```

instead of the validation For and see if this also happens on your side?

Also i notice this seems to be a long oustanding issue, just stumbled on another related issue on

[How to reset custom validation errors when using editform in blazor razor page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917323/how-to-reset-custom-validation-errors-when-using-editform-in-blazor-razor-page)

Comment: Display the model in which it is used. Display the form elements in which it is used, including the "submit" button

Comment: This is the form element

Comment: <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Amount</label>
                <InputNumber @bind-Value="@Transaction.Amount"  type="text" class="form-control required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: And the beolow is the model definition

Comment: [RequireGreaterThanZero]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; } = 0.00M;

Comment: The submit button is as below

 
<div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" style="width:100%" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Save"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> @ButtonText</button>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: @XtremeKeyboard.  Hi, can you add them to the question rather than as comments.  They are rather difficult to put into context as they are.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, have edited the question and included them

Answer (score 0):

Based on the update question I think a quick explanation of how validation works will help.

`DataAnnotationValidator` is a component that captures the `EditContext`cascaded by `EditForm` and registers for the Validation and Field Changed events on the `EditContext`. When these events occur it runs whatever validations it finds on the model and logs the results to a `ValidationMessageStore` in the `EditContext`.   It doesn't display anything, and should only occur once within the `EditForm`.

`ValidationSummary` and `ValidationMessage` are the display components.  They capture the `EditContext` cascaded by `EditForm` and either display all the messages in the `ValidationMessageStore`, or only the relevant message for the defined model property.

Here's my minimum reproducible demo code.  If you take it and run it you'll find:

- as you change the number up and down the validation message appears and disappears.
- as you enter a number and click/tab away from the field it updates the validation message.

So, what's the difference between your code and my demo code?

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp4.Data

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm EditContext=this.editContext OnValidSubmit=this.ValidSubmit>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Amount</label>
                <InputNumber @bind-Value="@this.model.Amount" type="text" class="form-control required" />

                <ValidationMessage For="() => this.model.Amount" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

</EditForm>


@code {
    private Model model = new Model();
    private EditContext? editContext;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.editContext = new EditContext(this.model);
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void ValidSubmit()
    {
        var x = true;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        [RequireGreaterThanZero]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; } = 0.00M;
    }
}
```

For reference my "Nullable" `RequireGreaterThanZeroAttribute`

```
public class RequireGreaterThanZeroAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var isValid = value is not null 
            && decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out decimal objectValue) 
            && objectValue > 0;

        return isValid
            ? ValidationResult.Success
            : new ValidationResult($"{validationContext.DisplayName} must be greater than zero.");
    }
}
```

Comment: ,have tested your solution and updated my question with more info.

Comment: I think you may not be configuring data validation in the form correctly.  See my updated answer.  If this doesn't explain things, put you full form in the question.  Note: there should only be one instance of `DataAnnotationValidator` in the form.

Comment: Also note the problem you highlighted was in trying to directly use `input` instead of the Blazor `InputBase` components and trying to shortcut/hack the message store and event logic.