# C#/Blazor - Returning Value From SQL for Use in Required

Tags: c#, blazor

Currently working on a group project involving a Blazor website with a SQL backend. One of the necessary functionalities is a user registration page that validates, among other things, that the entered email is unique. We have the validation logic set up, but the problem is that we can't figure out how to return an integer (or even just any value at all) to run against our validator.

```
public class PersonModel
{
    ...

    [Required]
    [CheckEmail(1, ErrorMessage = "Email is already in use.")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    ...
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the registration page:

```
@code{
...

    private async Task CheckEmail()
    {
        string sql = "select COUNT(*) from database.account where email=@email;";
        check = await _data.LoadData<PersonModel, dynamic>(sql, new {}, _config.GetConnectionString("default"));

       return check;
    }

...
}
```

Comment: You could put a unique index on it and test for conflict exception on add or update. You are capturing database update errors?

Comment: See my answer to this question on how to build a custom validation attribute -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075115/custom-validation-attribute-does-not-immediately-clear-error-when-value-is-fixed/72083673#72083673