# Data Annotations C# Two StringLegth Possibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations

I have this propery in my C# class:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Document must contain only numbers")]
public string DocRegister{ get; set; }
```

Beyond that, I need to validade the length of the string. It's acceptable the length **11** OR **14**
How can I do that with Data Annotations?

I mean, I couldn't do:

```
[StringLength(11, MinimumLength = 11)]
[StringLength(14, MinimumLength = 14)]
```

right?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with data annotations.  You could use a library like FluentValidation to do this, though.

Comment: As workaround you can try to write regex which will do that)

Comment: Or write your own custom [annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413875/2501279).