# Apply ValidationAttributes from DataAnnotation to all elements of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I am using `Microsoft.Extension.Options` in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I want to validate entries in an configuration file.

For this I want that, e.g. a `RangeAttribute` is applied to each element of an `IEnumerable`.

```cs
class MyConfiguration
{
    [ApplyToItems]
    [Range(1, 10)]
    publlic IList<int> MyConfigValues { get; set; }
}
```

Or something like that. How do I write the `ApplyToItems` method?

As far as I know there is no way to retrieve the other `ValidationAttributes` while a possible `ApplyToItems` is validated.

Alternatively I could imagine something like:

```
[Apply(Range(1, 10)]
public List<int> MyConfigValues { get; set; }
```

but is that even valid syntax? How would I write an Attribute like Apply that takes other Attributes as parameter without falling back on something like

```
[Apply(new RangeAttribute(1, 10)]
```

which does not look nice.

Answer (score 3):

To create a custom data annotation validator follow these gudelines:

1. Your class has to inherit from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute class.
2. Override bool IsValid(object value) method and implement validation logic inside it.

That's it.

(from  [How to create Custom Data Annotation Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators))

So in your case it could be something like this:

```
public class ApplyRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int Minimum { get; set; }
    public int Maximum { get; set; }

    public ApplyRangeAttribute()
    {
        this.Minimum = 0;
        this.Maximum = int.MaxValue;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is IList<int> list)
        {
            if (list.Any(i => i < Minimum || i > Maximum))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

### Edit

Here's how you would use it:

```
class MyConfiguration
{
    [ApplyRange(Minimum = 1, Maximum = 10)]
    public IList<int> MyConfigValues { get; set; }
}
```