Implement custom validation message in pipeline of filters
I have the following class that it's used by a Web API
public class PostJobRequest
{
    public int NumberOfThreads { get; set; }

    public bool ReprocessSuccessful { get; set; } = true;

    public bool ReprocessFailed { get; set; } = true;

    public bool ProcessNew { get; set; } = true;
}

The following JSON is sent to the Web API
{
    "NumberOfThreads": 4,
    "ReprocessSuccessful": 1,
    "ReprocessFailed": 1,
    "ProcessNew": 1
}

As you can see ReprocessSuccessful, ReprocessFailed, and ProcessNew are boolean type, but the JSON is sent with number types.
Then, the framework is returning the following error message:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "request": [
            "The request field is required."
        ],
        "$.ReprocessSuccessful": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.ReprocessSuccessful | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 28."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "00-00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000000000-00"
}

This is the expected behavior, but I need to return a JSON that reports all fields with invalid values, instead of just one of them. Something like this:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "request": [
            "The request field is required."
        ],
        "$.ReprocessSuccessful": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.ReprocessSuccessful | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 28."
        ],
        "$.ReprocessFailed": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.ReprocessFailed | LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 24."
        ],
        "$.ProcessNew": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.ProcessNew | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 19."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "00-00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000000000-00"
}

As you see, the JSON has the three fields with validation errors:
        "$.ReprocessSuccessful": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.ReprocessSuccessful | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 28."
        ],
        "$.ReprocessFailed": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.ReprocessFailed | LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 24."
        ],
        "$.ProcessNew": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.ProcessNew | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 19."
        ]

I considered creating my custom filter to achieve this, but the OnActionExecuting method only receives the context with the error in the ReprocessSuccessful field, omitting the other fields:
public class CustomModelStateFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }
}

Do you know if there is a way to change this behavior?

How are you validating the model? If you're using data annotations, you can just create a custom validator (ValidationAttribute) and wrap it on each property. Inside that validator set the error and then inside your controller or endpoint just check if the model state is valid. The ModelState should have all of the errors from the validator.

Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413715/how-to-create-custom-data-annotation-validators

This isn't a validation error, this exception is thrown during json parsing & serialisation. For performance and memory use reasons, the System.Text.Json library parses json and materialises the resulting classes in one pass, and doesn't distinguish between invalid json syntax and invalid serialisation semantics.
